# Terminal Server connection displays lock screen after unlocking local machine

Tags: virtual-machine, screensaver, terminal-services

In my environment, all my users log in to their Windows 7 computer and then immediately initiate a remote session to a virtual desktop on a Server 2012 machine. All their work is done on the remote desktop; nothing run on the local machine except the RDP session. All users are in a Users OU, the local machines are in a Computers OU, and the server is in a Server OU.

Thanks to SOX compliance, I had to enable a password protected screensaver on teh local machines. No problem: just create a GPO to enable the screen saver and apply it to the Users OU. We don't want the screen saver to show up on the TS session. Again, no problem: create a loopback policy to disable the screen saver, set it to merge, and apply it to the Server OU.

The problem is that now when a user comes back from lunch or break or even just starring into space for 15 minutes, they have to log in to their local machine AND ALSO the remote session. How can I disable locking the remote session?

Comment: Are you *sure* your group policy settings are working as expected? Locking the local machine has no effect on the lock status of an RDP session.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator That's what I thought too, except that before I made the screensaver GPO, waking the monitors after 30 minutes would not require any logins on either local or remote machines. This only started happening after enabling the screensaver on the local machine. :/

Comment: I suggest a sanity check: disable the GPO and confirm the behavior still exists.